# How do i read and store items from a csv file into 2D arrays in python?

Tags: python, csv, multidimensional-array

So I've been tasked with creating a suitable 2D array to contain all of the data from a csv with data on rainfall from the whole year. In the csv file, the rows represent the weeks of the year and the columns represent the day of the week.

I'm able to display the date I want using the following code.

```
import csv
data = list(csv.reader(open("rainfall.csv")))
print(data[1][2])
```

My issue is I'm not sure how to store this data in a 2D array.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy for that. It seems to me, that you have created a list of lists in data. With that you can directly create a 2D numpy-array:

```
import numpy as np


2d_data = np.array(data)
```

Or you could even try to directly read the file with numpy:

```
import numpy as np


# Use the appropriate delimiter here
2d_data = np.genfromtxt("rainfall.csv", delimiter=",")
```

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd


# Use the appropriate delimiter here
2d_data = pd.read_csv("rainfall.csv")
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response! I've never used lumpy before, I'll look into it! Is there another way of doing it, a friend I asked said this way might work:            ```import csv

file = open("nameOfFile.csv","r")
counter = 0
for row in file.readlines():
  array[counter][0] = row[0]
  array[counter][1] = row[1]
  array[counter][2] = row[2]
  array[counter][3] = row[3]
  counter += 1
file.close() ```

Comment: numpy* . sorry for the format

Comment: Sure, you could do it like this probably (you need to initialize `array` though with the correct dimensions). But then you'll just have a list of lists not really a 2D-array like in numpy. It behaves somewhat the same in certain ways, but not in others, depending on what you want to do with it, that can make a difference. I'd advise you to just use numpy, if you'll use python more often that's learning-time well spend, as numpy is one of the most important and useful libraries.

Comment: Probably it's even better, to use `pandas` in your case. I first thought about `numpy` when you said 2D-array. But probably you just want a table with records of the rainfall-events, that sounds more like a job for pandas to me. Numpy shines, when you get into more high-dimensional data and do a lot of matrix-calculations etc. Pandas is more suitable for tabular data (like in your case) especially if you have different data-types in each row (integers, strings, dates, etc.). There is a `pandas.read_csv`-function that you can use to read in csv-data. I added the pandas-version.